# Método virtual com Generic C#

Tags: c#, winforms, método, genéricos

Estou criando um Formulário base onde não estou usando ele de tipo "Generic" devido a problema com herança de formulários em C# com o mesmo.

Nesse formulário base, tive a necessidade de criar um método virtual com "Generic", pois o mesmo será sobrescrito na classe filha.

Ao dar o override do método na classe filha e "Trocar" o generic pela classe que estou implementando me deparo com o seguinte erro de compilação.

Error   1   'Projeto.ERP.Desktop.FormularioEstado.ObterRegistrosParaPopularGridView(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)': no suitable method found to override   C:\Users\Nicola Bogar\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Projeto.ERP.Solution\Projeto.ERP.Desktop\FormularioEstado.cs    39  38  Projeto.ERP.Desktop

> Formulário Pai

```
public partial class FormularioBase : Form
{

    public virtual List<object> ObterRegistrosParaPopularGridView<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Método ObterRegistrosParaPopularGridView da classe FormularioBase não implentada.");
    }
}
```

> Formulário Filho

```
public partial class FormularioEstado : FormularioBase
{
    public override List<object> ObterRegistrosParaPopularGridView<Estado>(Expression<Func<Estado, bool>> where = null)
    {
        using (ProjetoContext contexto = new ProjetoContext())
        {
            if (where == null)
            {
                return contexto.Estados.Include(x => x.Pais)
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Handle = x.Handle,
                        Descricao = x.Descricao,
                        Sigla = x.Sigla,
                        Pais = x.Pais,
                        PaisHandle = x.PaisHandle,
                        PaisDescricao = x.Pais.Descricao,
                        DataCadastro = x.DataCadastro,
                        DataAlteracao = x.DataAlteracao
                    }).ToList<object>();
            }
            else
            {
                return contexto.Estados
                    .Where(where)
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Handle = x.Handle,
                        Descricao = x.Descricao,
                        Sigla = x.Sigla,
                        Pais = x.Pais,
                        PaisHandle = x.PaisHandle,
                        PaisDescricao = x.Pais.Descricao,
                        DataCadastro = x.DataCadastro,
                        DataAlteracao = x.DataAlteracao
                    }).ToList<object>();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie o método genérico, ***exemplo minimo***:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public virtual List<T>
           ObterRegistrosParaPopularGridView<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where = null)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("---");
    }
}

public class Class2: Class1
{
    public override List<User> 
     ObterRegistrosParaPopularGridView<User>(Expression<Func<User, bool>> where = null)
    {
        return base.ObterRegistrosParaPopularGridView(where);
    }
}
```

No seu código ficaria algo assim:

```
public partial class FormularioBase : Form
{
    public virtual List<T>
     ObterRegistrosParaPopularGridView<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where = null)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Método ObterRegistrosParaPopularGridView ...");
    }
}
```

Método reescrito:

```
public override List<Estado> 
 ObterRegistrosParaPopularGridView<Estado>(Expression<Func<Estado, bool>> where = null)
{
    return base.ObterRegistrosParaPopularGridView(where);
}
```

Comment: Virgilio Novic, meu retorno na lista tem que ser um Objeto, pois estou usando o entityframework e estou realizando join em tabelas, ou seja, o retorno não é a mesma classe que estou realizando o where, creio que não seja esse o problema, pois criei igualzinho você mandou menos o retorno como generic, mas acho que o C# tem algum contrato que força o método override ser igualzinho o definido na classe PAI.

Comment: acabei editando o post devido esquecer de colocar <Estado> no método que estou realizando o override certo. Mas mesmo assim o problema persiste. Fiz um teste aqui e quando estou fazendo do jeito que você me mandou, ObterRegistrosParaPopularGridView<Estado>(Expression<Func<Estado, bool>> where = null) O <Estado> que está bem a frente do método o C# reconhece como Generic, dai ele não encontra realmente a classe que estou tentando usar, compreende ? Esse é o problema.. =/

Comment: Ok , perai, vou editar o posto.. Momentoo.

Comment: Veja se a edição ajuda alguma coisa amigo.

Comment: Concordo contigo nessa questão, mas é que esse select é apenas para popular grid, apenas uso o objeto para realizar o where na entidade que estou trabalhando.